# Could not find ildasm.exe

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, sdk, msbuild, ildasm

I recently upgraded to VS 2017 and uninstalled the previous VS 2015.

However when I try and build and compile my project I keep getting and error:

`Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper could not find ildasm.exe`

The project uses Unmanaged Exports for C# - https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports

I cannot understand why this message comes up and googling has showed nothing. I have made sure that the target framework is the same >> **4.5.2**. But nothing will build!!

I could only find the following directories though:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools`

Please help, thanks

Comment: Could it be that the uninstall of VS 2015 remove the file you want to use? Just a thought.

Comment: @user3454439 - that is what I fear :(

Comment: @KenWhite- I have looked on my hard drive, I have the ildasm.exe for the NET 4.6.1 tools but no folder for NET 4.5.2. Whatever I try and install will never get me back that folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this issue: https://github.com/nefarius/ViGEm/issues/29

You should reinstall VS2017. Uninstall all of your VS15/17 versions and install it again with the VS17 installer.

Answer (score 5):

Update with the latest version of UnmangedExports. In my case, it was version 1.2.7

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem.

I installed the Unmanaged Exports again and the problem was solved.

Comment: There is a newer open source version of Unmanaged Exports on github. I'd recommend using this one as it will support later version of .NET framework - https://github.com/3F/DllExport

Answer (score 2):

I have vs2015 installed, and I had that trouble, and using this command       PM>Install-Package UnmanagedExports -Version 1.2.7 on nuget console, and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

If reinstall doesn't resolve problem, remove folder packages\UnmanagedExports.1.2.7 and then, in Package Manager Console, install package using command posted by @Ale:

```
PM>Install-Package UnmanagedExports -Version 1.2.7
```